# "cannot find symbol method add(java.util.Date)"

Tags: java

I'm getting an error "cannot find symbol method add(java.util.Date)", although what I'm passing it was declared a Date.  What am I missing?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.*;


class Entry {
    Date date;

    Entry(Date aDate) {
        date = aDate;
    }
}

public class td {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date aDate = df.parse("2011-02-27"); // Date aDate = new Date() also fails

        entries.add(aDate);

        System.out.println(entries.get(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: A more specific case of the general question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure you want not `entries.add(new Entry(aDate));` ?  It seems to be the purpose of `Entry` class.

And generally speaking, if you declare list as `List<Entry>`, you should store `Entry` instances in it, not `Date`.

Also, your error says "cannot find symbol *method add(java.util.Date)*" . So, it's not `Date` class that's missing. It's `add(java.util.Date)` method.

Comment: Sigh.  You're right.  The compiler also insists that I wrap the df.parse statement with try & catch.  While I'm at it, I should have entries.get() return something sensible.

Comment: @foosion Instead of wrapping, it might be easier to add `throws Exception` to the `main` method declaration. Since you can't do anything useful with error, it's better to just let it pass.

Comment: That is easier.  It also prevents "not initialized" errors if I don't declare and initialize aDate outside the try/catch

Answer (score 0):

To re-iterate: List has add(Entry) method and doesn't have add(Date) method.